# Send data from activity to fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two classes. First is activity, second is a fragment where I have some `EditText`. In activity I have a subclass with async-task and in method `doInBackground` I get some result, which I save to variable. How can I send this variable from subclass "my activity" to this fragment?

Comment: Bundles and intents are not working for me so the ViewModelProvider is the better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135731/passing-data-through-navigation-between-fragments-android-studio/78214917#78214917.

Answer (score 743, accepted):

From Activity  you send data with intent as:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
// set Fragmentclass Arguments
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Hmm I get a NullPointerException when calling `getArguments().getString(key)`

Comment: @Nima : hi, please share relevant part of code and error log then i will try to help you sure.Thanks

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK The thing is, you should set the bundle before the fragment is added to Activity or you'll get NPE.

Comment: Null Pointer Exception when calling load_url = getArguments().getString("edttext");

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K: can we share data between Fragment to Activity? If yes then how?

Comment: NullPointerException "String strtext setArguments().getString("edttext");"

Comment: While reading the bundle content in fragment always first receive the bundle into a Bundle object using getArguments method and check it against null. Otherwise,  getString method will be applied on null and so the NPE when no bundle is passed. This will avoid the null pointer exceptions when the bundle is not passed.

Comment: great answer brother but after doing same thing its not working for me,and showing error near my declaration of string in my fragment page

Comment: And what about class constructor? Why not use constructor like 
`
public FragmentWallet(String accountNo) {
        this.accountNo = accountNo;
    }
`

Comment: @Aznix. It is not recommended to create constructor for fragment.

Comment: and for other way around ? i mean if my fragment creates an activity which calls a fragment. now i want to pass back some data from that activity once it finishes to my fragment that created this activity ! Thanks

Comment: @k2ibegin: For this start Activity using `startActivityForResult` method and override `onActivityResult` in Activity in which Fragment is Added.  to get data from `onActivityResult` to Fragment create a method in Fragment and call it using same object which u have used for adding Fragment in FragmentManager

Comment: How about if I have fragment in xml, like this `<fragment android:name="com.picker.PickerListFragment"`?? How can we send data from `Activity` to this `PickerListFragment`??

Comment: @yeahman yes, you can pass object but your objects implements serializable

Comment: For NPE, don't forget in you activity, after you create the fragment using static factory, to remove "fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());" from android example page, since that would replace the arguments, that you have passed into the static factory.

Comment: isn't this useless since `onCreateView` isn't called for subsequent fragment references? so it only works the first time

Comment: Not far from a possible answer to the problem encountered... but the question was about passing data after an asyncTask: the fragment is supposed to be already created and committed. @ρяσѕρєяK more upvotes coming if you adapt the answer to an already committed fragment ;)

Comment: every one is just sending and passing text, but my scenario is a bit different  ... don't you see there are much other things than text/string i.e. Custom Class, List<Custom Class> etc... so how to pass such type of data from activity to fragment.

Comment: getArguments() always null!

Comment: After so long I would think that Android would create a simple way to attach any type of data to a fragment seeing that its such an important part of their software. I have read all of the answers and the accepted answer seems to be the simplest but still requires serializing every type of data. Its amazing what programmers have to go through to do some of the most trivial things.

Answer (score 127):

Also You can access activity data from fragment:

**Activity:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private String myString = "hello";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        ...
    }

    public String getMyData() {
        return myString;
    }
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        MyActivity activity = (MyActivity) getActivity();
        String myDataFromActivity = activity.getMyData();
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution integrates tight coupling between your activity and Fragment, better to use the `Bundle` class to pass information. Alternatively you could make that `getMyData()` method inherited and implemented from an interface and have the `Fragment` check whether getActivity returns an `instanceof` the Interface in `onAttach()`.

Comment: This solution best for me. Also if myString be public, you have not declare getMyData() method

Comment: Current accepted answer returns null pointer exception. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: This should *not* be the accepted answer. The tight coupling is easily avoidable. This is generally a bad idea, and makes the fragment useless, might as well not have a fragment if you're only going to use it tied to an activity. The fragment cannot be reused in other activities.

Comment: This works for my needs, I need to pass a custom object list and I don't believe I can do that with the Bundle answer.

Answer (score 59):

I´ve found a lot of answers here @ stackoverflow.com but definitely this is the correct answer of:

#### "Sending data from activity to fragment in android".

**Activity:**

```
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        String myMessage = "Stackoverflow is cool!";
        bundle.putString("message", myMessage );
        FragmentClass fragInfo = new FragmentClass();
        fragInfo.setArguments(bundle);
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_single, fragInfo);
        transaction.commit();
```

**Fragment:**

Reading the value in the fragment

```
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        String myValue = bundle.getString("message");
        ...
        ...
        ...
        }
```

or just

```
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String myValue = this.getArguments().getString("message");
        ...
        ...
        ...
        }
```

Comment: I guess that's not the best approach for updating onQueryTextSubmit-search-results in a ListView, which is nested inside a Fragment (if somybody types fast, he will send the args twice a second)?

Comment: What about Object insted of string or int?

Comment: @Jorgesys What about this solution? https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Thanks Yozhik, I knew he was missing something with the random "transaction" variables.

Answer (score 31):

This answer may be too late. but it will be useful for future readers.

I have some criteria. I have coded for pick the file from intent. and selected file to be passed to particular fragment for further process. i have many fragments having the functionality of File picking. at the time , every time checking the condition and get the fragment and pass the value is quite disgusting. so , i have decided to pass the value using interface.

**Step 1:** Create the interface on Main Activity.

```
   public interface SelectedBundle {
    void onBundleSelect(Bundle bundle);
   }
```

**Step 2:** Create the SelectedBundle reference on the Same Activity

```
   SelectedBundle selectedBundle;
```

**Step 3:** create the Method in the Same Activity

```
   public void setOnBundleSelected(SelectedBundle selectedBundle) {
       this.selectedBundle = selectedBundle;
   }
```

**Step 4:** Need to initialise the SelectedBundle reference which are all fragment need filepicker functionality.You place this code on your fragment `onCreateView(..)` method

```
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setOnBundleSelected(new MainActivity.SelectedBundle() {
          @Override
         public void onBundleSelect(Bundle bundle) {
            updateList(bundle);
        }
     });
```

**Step 5:** My case, i need to pass the image Uri from HomeActivity to fragment. So, i used this functionality on onActivityResult method.

onActivityResult from the MainActivity, pass the values to the fragments using interface.

**Note:**  Your case may be different. you can call it from any where from your HomeActivity.

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent  data) {
       selectedBundle.onBundleSelect(bundle);
  }
```

Thats all. Implement every fragment you needed on the FragmentClass. You are great. you have done. WOW...

Answer (score 20):

The best and convenient approach is calling fragment instance and send data at that time.
**every fragment by default have instance method**

> For example :
>   if your fragment name is **MyFragment**

so you will call your fragment from activity like this :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, MyFragment.newInstance("data1","data2"),"MyFragment").commit();
```

***R.id.container is a id of my FrameLayout**

so in **MyFragment.newInstance("data1","data2")** you can send data to fragment and in your fragment you get this data in **MyFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2)**

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

and then in **onCreate** method of fragment you'll get the data:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }
```

> so now **mParam1 have data1** and **mParam2 have data2**
>
> now you can use this **mParam1** and **mParam2**  in your fragment.

Comment: what is R.id.container here? did you mean R.id.container_current this is an int value.

Comment: @s *R.id.container is a id of my FrameLayout

Comment: So far the best explanation I've ever found to pass data on add/replace fragment using Fragment Manager. Works like gem! Thanks!

Comment: used R.id.nav_host_fragment instead of R.id.container

Answer (score 16):

Basic Idea of using Fragments (F) is to create reusable self sustaining UI components in android applications. These Fragments are contained in activities and there are common(best) way of creating communication path ways from A -> F and  F-A, It is a must to Communicate between F-F through a Activity because then only the Fragments become decoupled and self sustaining.

So passing data from A -> F is going to be the same as explained by ρяσѕρєя K. In addition to that answer, After creation of the Fragments inside an Activity, we can also pass data to the fragments calling methods in Fragments.

For example:

```
    ArticleFragment articleFrag = (ArticleFragment)
                    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.article_fragment);
    articleFrag.updateArticleView(position);
```

Comment: proof: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 13):

I would like to add for the beginners that the difference between the 2 most upvoted answers here is given by the different use of a fragment.

If you use the fragment within the java class where you have the data you want to pass, you can apply the first answer to pass data:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");
Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

If however you use for example the default code given by Android Studio for tabbed fragments, this code will not work.

It will not work even if you replace the default PlaceholderFragment with your FragmentClasses, and even if you correct the FragmentPagerAdapter to the new situation adding a switch for getItem() and another switch for getPageTitle() (as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00LLd7qr9sA&list=PL200JxfhYIgAfRaMIg7aIIjLrpM9EiAdl))

*Warning: the clip mentioned above has code errors, which I explain later here, but is useful to see how you go from default code to editable code for tabbed fragments)! The rest of my answer makes much more sense if you consider the java classes and xml files from that clip (representative for a first use of tabbed fragments by a beginner scenario).*

The main reason the most upvoted answer from this page will not work is that in that default code for tabbed fragments, the fragments are used in another java class: FragmentPagerAdapter!

So, in order to send the data, you are tempted to create a bundle in the MotherActivity and pass it in the FragmentPagerAdapter, using answer no.2.

Only that is wrong again. (*Probably you could do it like that, but it is just a complication which is not really needed*).

The correct/easier way to do it, I think, is to pass the data directly to the fragment in question, using answer no.2.
Yes, there will be tight coupling between the Activity and the Fragment, BUT, for tabbed fragments, that is kind of expected. I would even advice you to create the tabbed fragments inside the MotherActivity java class (as subclasses, as they will never be used outside the MotherActivity) - it is easy, just add inside the MotherActivity java class as many Fragments as you need like this:

```
 public static class Tab1 extends Fragment {

    public Tab1() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_name_for_fragment_1, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}.
```

So, to pass data from the MotherActivity to such a Fragment you will need to create private Strings/Bundles above the onCreate of your Mother activity - which you can fill with the data you want to pass to the fragments, and pass them on via a method created after the onCreate (here called getMyData()).

```
public class MotherActivity extends Activity {

    private String out;
    private Bundle results;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mother_activity);

       // for example get a value from the previous activity
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        out = intent.getExtras().getString("Key");

    }

    public Bundle getMyData() {
        Bundle hm = new Bundle();
        hm.putString("val1",out);
        return hm;
    }
}
```

And then in the fragment class, you use getMyData:

```
public static class Tab1 extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public Tab1() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_name_for_fragment_1, container, false);
            TextView output = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.your_id_for_a_text_view_within_the_layout);

            MotherActivity activity = (MotherActivity)getActivity();

            Bundle results = activity.getMyData();
            String value1 = results.getString("val1");

            output.setText(value1);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

If you have database queries I advice you to do them in the MotherActivity (and pass their results as Strings/Integers attached to keys inside a bundle as shown above), as inside the tabbed fragments, your syntax will become more complex (this becomes getActivity() for example, and getIntent becomes getActivity().getIntent), but you have also the option to do as you wish.

My advice for beginners is to focus on small steps. First, get your intent to open a very simple tabbed activity, without passing ANY data. Does it work? Does it open the tabs you expect? If not, why?

Start from that, and by applying solutions such as those presented in [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00LLd7qr9sA&list=PL200JxfhYIgAfRaMIg7aIIjLrpM9EiAdl), see what is missing. For that particular clip, the mainactivity.xml is never shown. That will surely confuse you. But if you pay attention, you will see that for example the context (tools:context) is wrong in the xml fragment files. Each fragment XML needs to point to the correct fragment class (or subclass using the separator $).

You will also see that in the main activity java class you need to add tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager) - right after the line TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs); without this line, your view is actually not linked to the XML files of the fragments, but it shows ONLY the xml file of the main activity.

In addition to the line in the main activity java class, in the main activity XML file you need to change the tabs to fit your situation (e.g. add or remove TabItems).  If you do not have tabs in the main activity XML, then possibly you did not choose the correct activity type when you created it in the first place (new activity - tabbed activity).

Please note that in the last 3 paragraphs I talk about the video! So when I say main activity XML, it is the main activity XML in the video, which in your situation is the MotherActivity XML file.

Answer (score 8):

If you pass a reference to the (concrete subclass of) fragment into the async task, you can then access the fragment directly.

Some ways of passing the fragment reference into the async task:

- If your async task is a fully fledged class (`class FooTask extends AsyncTask`), then pass your fragment into the constructor.
- If your async task is an inner class, just declare a final Fragment variable in the scope the async task is defined, or as a field of the outer class.  You'll be able to access that from the inner class.

Answer (score 8):

From `Activity` you send data with Bundle as:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("data", "Data you want to send");

// Your fragment
MyFragment obj = new MyFragment();
obj.setArguments(bundle);
```

And in `Fragment` onCreateView method get the data:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    String data = getArguments().getString("data");// data which sent from activity  
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment, container, false);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes you can receive Intent in your activity and you need to pass the info to your working fragment.
Given answers are OK if you need to start the fragment but if it's still working, `setArguments()` is not very useful.
Another problem occurs if the passed information will cause to interact with your UI. In that case you cannot call something like `myfragment.passData()` because android will quickly tells that only the thread which created the view can interact with.

So my proposal is to use a receiver. That way, you can send data from anywhere, including the activity, but the job will be done within the fragment's context.

In you fragment's `onCreate()`:

```
protected DataReceiver dataReceiver;
public static final String REC_DATA = "REC_DATA";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    data Receiver = new DataReceiver();
    intentFilter = new IntentFilter(REC_DATA);

    getActivity().registerReceiver(dataReceiver, intentFilter);
}

private class DataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int data= intent.getIntExtra("data", -1);

        // Do anything including interact with your UI
    }
}
```

In you activity:

```
// somewhere
Intent retIntent = new Intent(RE_DATA);
retIntent.putExtra("data", myData);
sendBroadcast(retIntent);
```

Answer (score 5):

Very old post, still I dare to add a little explanation that would had been helpful for me.

Technically you can directly set members of any type in a fragment from activity.
So why Bundle?
The reason is very simple - Bundle provides uniform way to handle:
-- creating/opening fragment
-- reconfiguration (screen rotation) - just add initial/updated bundle to outState in onSaveInstanceState()
-- app restoration after being garbage collected in background (as with reconfiguration).

You can (if you like experiments) create a workaround in simple situations but Bundle-approach just doesn't see difference between one fragment and one thousand on a backstack - it stays simple and straightforward. 
That's why the answer by **@Elenasys** is the most elegant and universal solution.
 And that's why the answer given by **@Martin** has **pitfalls**

Answer (score 5):

If an `activity` needs to make a `fragment` perform an action after initialization, the easiest way is by having the `activity` invoke a method on the `fragment` instance. In the `fragment`, add a method:

```
public class DemoFragment extends Fragment {
  public void doSomething(String param) {
      // do something in fragment
  }
}
```

and then in the `activity`, get access to the `fragment` using the `fragment` manager and call the `method`:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DemoFragment fragmentDemo = (DemoFragment) 
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentDemo);
        fragmentDemo.doSomething("some param");
    }
}
```

and then the `activity` can communicate directly with the `fragment` by invoking this `method`.

Comment: this is really nice, in the sense that you dont want to enter into `onCreateView` method in the fragment. was really helpful

Answer (score 4):

the better approach for sending data from activity class to fragment is passing via setter methods. Like

```
FragmentClass fragmentClass = new FragmentClass();
fragmentClass.setMyList(mylist);
fragmentClass.setMyString(myString);
fragmentClass.setMyMap(myMap);
```

and get these data from the class easily.

Comment: How to pass data from fragment to fragment like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953477/pass-data-to-fragment

Comment: This is not very convenient when you are also passing along other, previously set Extra's

Comment: If you need that data to be set to some field in your fragment, and it's not yet visible (initialized) you'll get NPE.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: I stopped working with Android likely 3 years ago, these things may be deprecated these days.

Comment: Not working as of today. Please update the answer to use a bundle

Answer (score 2):

Use following interface to communicate between activity and fragment

```
public interface BundleListener {
    void update(Bundle bundle);
    Bundle getBundle();
}
```

Or use following this generic listener for two way communication using interface

```
 /**
 * Created by Qamar4P on 10/11/2017.
 */
public interface GenericConnector<T,E> {
    T getData();
    void updateData(E data);
    void connect(GenericConnector<T,E> connector);
}
```

fragment show method

```
public static void show(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        CustomValueDialogFragment dialog = new CustomValueDialogFragment();
        dialog.connector = (GenericConnector) activity;
        dialog.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(),"CustomValueDialogFragment");
    }
```

you can cast your context to `GenericConnector` in `onAttach(Context)` too

in your activity

```
CustomValueDialogFragment.show(this);
```

in your fragment

```
...
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        connector.connect(new GenericConnector() {
            @Override
            public Object getData() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void updateData(Object data) {

            }

            @Override
            public void connect(GenericConnector connector) {

            }
        });
    }
...
    public static void show(AppCompatActivity activity, GenericConnector connector) {
            CustomValueDialogFragment dialog = new CustomValueDialogFragment();
            dialog.connector = connector;
            dialog.show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(),"CustomValueDialogFragment");
        }
```

Note: Never use it like `"".toString().toString().toString();` way.

Answer (score 2):

just stumbled across this question, while most of the methods above will work.
I just want to add that you can use the [Event Bus Library](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/), especially in scenarios where the component (Activity or Fragment) has not been created, its good for all sizes of android projects and many use cases. I have personally used it in several projects i have on playstore.

Answer (score 1):

You can create public static method in fragment where you will get static reference of that fragment and then pass data to that function and set that data to argument in same method and get data via getArgument on oncreate method of fragment, and set that data to local variables.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue while using the latest Navigation architecture component. Tried out all the above-mentioned code with passing a bundle from my calling activity to Fragment.

The best solution, following the latest development trends in Android, is by using View Model (part of Android Jetpack).

Create and Initialize a ViewModel class in the parent Activity, Please note that this ViewModel has to be shared between the activity and fragment.

Now, Inside the onViewCreated() of the fragment, Initialize the Same ViewModel and setup Observers to listen to the ViewModel fields.

Here is a helpful, in-depth tutorial if you need.

https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-communicate-between-fragments-and-activity-using-viewmodel-ca733233a51c

Answer (score 1):

**Kotlin** version:

In `Activity`:

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putBoolean("YourKey1", true)
bundle.putString("YourKey2", "YourString")

val fragment = YourFragment()
fragment.arguments = bundle
val fragmentTransaction = parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.your_container, fragment, fragment.toString())
fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

In the `Fragment` onCreate():

```
var value1 = arguments?.getBoolean("YourKey1", default true/false)
var value2 = arguments?.getString("YourKey2", "Default String")
```

Answer (score 0):

Smartest tried and tested way of passing data between fragments and activity is to create a variables,example:

```
class StorageUtil {
  public static ArrayList<Employee> employees;
}
```

Then to pass data from fragment to activity, we do so in the onActivityCreated method:

```
//a field created in the sending fragment
ArrayList<Employee> employees;

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
         employees=new ArrayList();

       //java 7 and above syntax for arraylist else use employees=new ArrayList<Employee>() for java 6 and below

     //Adding first employee
        Employee employee=new Employee("1","Andrew","Sam","1984-04-10","Male","Ghanaian");
        employees.add(employee);

      //Adding second employee
       Employee employee=new Employee("1","Akuah","Morrison","1984-02-04","Female","Ghanaian");
         employees.add(employee);

        StorageUtil.employees=employees;
    }
```

Now you can get the value of StorageUtil.employees from everywhere.
Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to write a static method inside the fragment:

```
public TheFragment setData(TheData data) {
    TheFragment tf = new TheFragment();
    tf.data = data;
    return tf;
}
```

This way I am sure that all the data I need is inside the Fragment before any other possible operation which could need to work with it.
Also it looks cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Well, if TheData is not thread safe, making it static will not necessarily protect you from thread issues. Careful with that. Static is not thread safe by nature.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a setter method in the fragment. Then in the Activity, when you reference to the fragment, you call the setter method and pass it the data from you Activity

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for 3 days none of the solution worked for me here's the final one which worked-

Step 1- Create a ViewModel class for sharing data between the Activity and the Fragment.

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
private MutableLiveData<String> myData = new MutableLiveData<>();

public void setData(String data) {
    myData.setValue(data);
}

public LiveData<String> getData() {
    return myData;
}
```

}

Step 2- In the Activity, create an instance of the ViewModel and set the data using the setData() method.

```
MyViewModel myViewModel = new 
ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
myViewModel.setData("Hello from Activity!");
```

Step 3 - In the Fragment, get an instance of the ViewModel and observe the data using the getData() method.

```
        MyViewModel myViewModel = new 
        ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
        myViewModel.getData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new 
        Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String data) {
        // update UI with the new data
          }
        });
```

With these steps, the Fragment will be able to receive and update the data set in the ViewModel by the Activity. Note that the ViewModel is scoped to the Activity, so it will persist even if the Fragment is destroyed and recreated during configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin : data send activity to fragment side**

**step 1: activity**

```
class SurveyInfoActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
private lateinit var surveyPageOneFragment: SurveyPageOneFragment
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivitySurveyInfoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    init()
}
private fun init() {
    context = this
    binding.viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = false
    surveyPageOneFragment = SurveyPageOneFragment.newInstance(false)
}

/**
 * then getting your data any side to put on this method
 * ***/
surveyPageOneFragment.setFetchedActivityToFragOne(firstName,middleName,lastName, getMobileNum, getGender, bDay, bMonth, bYear, getAge, getBloodGroup)}
```

**step 2: Fragment one**

```
fun setFetchedActivityToFragOne(
    gFirstName: String?,
    gMiddleName : String?,
    gLastName: String?,
    gMobile: String?,
    gGender: String?,
    dd: String?,
    mm: String?,
    yyyy: String?,
    gAge: Int?,
    gBloodGroup: String?
){
    this.gFirstName = gFirstName
    this.gMiddleName = gMiddleName
    this.gLastName = gLastName
    this.gMobile = gMobile
    this.gender = gGender
    this.bDay = dd
    this.bMonth = mm
    this.bYear = yyyy
    this.niceAge = gAge
    this.bloodGroup = gBloodGroup
    Log.d("TAG", "Activity get First name: $gFirstName")
    Log.d("TAG", "Activity get middle name: $gMiddleName")
    Log.d("TAG", "Activity get last name: $gLastName")
    Log.d("TAG", "Activity get mobile: $gMobile")
    Log.d("TAG", "Activity get Gender: $gGender")
    Log.d("TAG", "Activity get birthDay: $dd")
    Log.d("TAG", "Activity get birthMonth: $mm")
    Log.d("TAG", "Activity get birthYear: $yyyy")
    Log.d("TAG", "Activity get age: $gAge")
    Log.d("TAG", "Activity get bloodGroup: $gBloodGroup")

    getActivityFetchData(gFirstName,gMiddleName, gLastName, gMobile, gGender,dd,mm,yyyy,gAge,gBloodGroup)
}
```

**step 3: get data and check value and set text or checkbox**

```
private fun getActivityFetchData(
    gName: String?,
    gMName: String?,
    gLName: String?,
    gMobile: String?,
    gGender: String?,
    gdd: String?,
    gmm: String?,
    gyyyy: String?,
    gAge: Int?,
    gBloodGroup: String?
){
    binding.edtYourName.setText(gName)
    binding.edtMiddleName.setText(gMName)
    binding.edtLastName.setText(gLName)
    binding.edtPhoneCall.setText(gMobile)

    when (gGender) {
        male -> {
            binding.cbMale.isChecked = true
        }
        female -> {
            binding.cbFemale.isChecked = true
        }
        other -> {
            binding.cbTransgender.isChecked = true
        }
    }

    binding.autoDay.setText(gdd)
    binding.autoMonth.setText(gmm)
    binding.autoYear.setText(gyyyy)
    binding.txtAge.text = gAge.toString()

    when (gBloodGroup) {
        posA -> {
            binding.cbPositiveA.isChecked = true
        }
        posB -> {
            binding.cbPositiveB.isChecked = true
        }
        posAB -> {
            binding.cbPositiveAb.isChecked = true
        }
        posO -> {
            binding.cbPositiveO.isChecked = true
        }
        negA -> {
            binding.cbNegativeA.isChecked = true
        }
        negB -> {
            binding.cbNegativeB.isChecked = true
        }
        negAB -> {
            binding.cbNegativeAb.isChecked = true
        }
        negO -> {
            binding.cbNegativeO.isChecked = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

In your activity declare static variable

```
public static HashMap<String,ContactsModal> contactItems=new HashMap<String, ContactsModal>();
```

Then in your fragment do like follow

```
ActivityName.contactItems.put(Number,contactsModal);
```

Comment: It will work but NOT RECOMMENDED. As static members will stay in the memory unless app is forced closed from recent apps. So in a case like this you should only use static member when you need it in many activity throughout the app.